# Email with Node.js and Express.js and AngularJs and nodemiailer not sending mail

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, nodemailer

I have looked at various tutorials and have done many searches on sending a basic email via an HTML and AngularJs page, using Node.js and Express.js, but simply cannot get it my implementation to work. I know I am missing something stupid.

I have opted to go with **nodemailer** as the Node.js package, and use this in my Express.js API to send the actual mail.

**The path from my view to the API is as follows**: View (form) >> Controller >> Email Factory >> API

I get a result (console log of the data) for each of these steps, however the email fails.

In the Chrome dev tools, I get a Status Code of `200 OK` in the Headers, but it actually failed. When I look under Response or Preview, I get the following message:

```
{error: "connect ETIMEDOUT 64.233.184.109:465"}
error:"connect ETIMEDOUT 64.233.184.109:465"
```

In the Bash console (where I am running my server) I can see the API endpoint is being hit, as I get this `console.log` output:

```
THIS IS THE API HIT:Email to: corne.leroux@outlook.comSubject: This is my subjectMessage: This is my message
```

**Some refs I have been using:**

http://javascript.tutorialhorizon.com/2015/07/02/send-email-node-js-express/

https://blog.ragingflame.co.za/2012/6/28/simple-form-handling-with-express-and-nodemailer

I am an absolute newb at Express.js, and have limited knowledge with Node.js.

**Here is my basic implementation:**

**HTML View:**

```
<div class="container">
    <form name="createEmailForm" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="emailAddress" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12 control-label">From Email Address</label>
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-xs-12">
                <input ng-model="formData.emailAddress" type="text" class="form-control" id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress" placeholder="Email Address" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="clientName" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-xs-12">
                <input ng-model="formData.clientName" type="text" class="form-control" id="clientName" name="clientName" placeholder="Name" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="clientMessage" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12 control-label">Message</label>
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-xs-12">
                <input ng-model="formData.clientMessage" type="text" class="form-control" id="clientMessage" name="clientMessage" placeholder="Message" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submit(formData)">Send</button>
</div>
```

**AngularJs Controller:**

```
$scope.submit = function () {
    var formData = $scope.formData;
    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.formData));
    sendMail(formData);
};

function sendMail(formData) {
    console.log('createEmail: ', formData);
    return EmailFactory.sendMail(formData)
        .then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("Email Sent");
        });
}
```

**AnularJs Factory:**

```
function sendMail() { 
    return $http.post('/api/send')
    .then(Success)
    .catch(Failure);

    function Success(responce) {
        console.log(responce.data);
        return responce.data;
    }

    function Failure(error) {
        console.log('A problem occurred while sending an email.' + JSON.stringify(error));
    }
}
```

**Express.js API**

```
var express = require('express');
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var customers = require('../schemas/customers.js');
var suppliers = require('../schemas/suppliers.js');
var products = require('../schemas/products.js');

var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    auth: {
        user: "cjleroux8@gmail.com",
        pass: "*********"
    }
});

router.post('/send', function (req, res, next) {
    var mailOptions = {
        to: req.body.emailAddress,
        subject: req.body.clientName,
        text: req.body.clientMessage
    }

    console.log('THIS IS THE API HIT:' + 'Email to: ' + mailOptions.to + 'Subject: ' + mailOptions.subject + 'Message: ' + mailOptions.text);

    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, response) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.json({error: "API Error"});
        } else {
            console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
            res.json({ response: "sent" });
        }
    });
});
```

**This is my app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var api = require('./routes/api');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_CON || 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27021/impi');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
// app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
// app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/api', api);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**This is my index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile('index.html');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Check whether request is coming to `/send`.

Comment: Code provided by you is incorrect. With this code you can't get any response from the server. For example I don't see `app.listen()` in app.js, also `sendMail()` in angularJs factory doesn't accept any parameters and sends to the server empty body.

Comment: @alexmac The data does get send to the API, and reaches the API. Please read through the question. I mentioned that the data is logged out during each step of the path to the API. Controller>>Factory>>API. The rest of my app has the similar implementation of the API and Factory, and it does indeed send data to the DB. It is only the email that does not get send.

Comment: do we need to give our own email and password of gmail or what ??? please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your factory function `sendMail` should have `formData` parameter and then sent that data in `post` request.
factory should be like:

```
function sendMail(formData) { 
    return $http.post('/api/send', formData)
    .then(Success)
    .catch(Failure);

    function Success(responce) {
        console.log(responce.data);
        return responce.data;
    }

    function Failure(error) {
        console.log('A problem occurred while sending an email.' + JSON.stringify(error));
    }
}
```

and for your `API`

to send email you should set `from` email for `nodemailer` so you can set like

```
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "Gmail",
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    auth: {
        user: "cjleroux8@gmail.com",
        pass: "*********"
    }
},
{
   from: 'example@gmail.com',
});

router.post('/api/send', function (req, res, next) {
    var mailOptions = {
        to: req.body.emailAddress,
        subject: req.body.clientName,
        text: req.body.clientMessage
    };

    console.log('THIS IS THE API HIT:' + 'Email to: ' + mailOptions.to + 'Subject: ' + mailOptions.subject + 'Message: ' + mailOptions.text);

    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, response) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.json({error: "API Error"});
        } else {
            console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
            res.json({ response: "sent" });
        }
    });
});
```

**OR** you can set `from` in `mailOptions`

```
var mailOptions = {
        from: 'example@gmail.com',
        to: req.body.emailAddress,
        subject: req.body.clientName,
        text: req.body.clientMessage
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Shaishab! It turned out that the only issue was the missing "from" email address. It doesn't matter what you name the parameter in the Factory (data/formData etc.) Once again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented an basic application of sending email using nodejs and express. I used nodemailer module but i have not added mongodb in my application. Check my code below if it is used to you.

**Index.html**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Node.JS Email application</title>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script>// <![CDATA[
         $(document).ready(function() {
            var from, to, subject, text;
            $("#send_email").click(function() {
                to = $("#to").val();
                subject = $("#subject").val();
                text = $("#content").val();
                $("#message").text("Sending E-mail...Please wait");
                $.get("http://192.168.2.47:3000/send", {
                    to: to,
                    subject: subject,
                    text: text
                }, function(data) {
                    if (data == "sent") {
                        $("#message").empty().html("Email is been sent at " + to + " Please check inbox!");
                    }

                });
            });
        });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="container">
         <h1>Mailer In Node.JS</h1>
         <br/>
         <input id="to" type="text" placeholder="Enter E-mail ID where you want to send" /><br/>
         <input id="subject" type="text" placeholder="Write Subject" /><br/>
         <textarea id="content" cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="Write what you want to send"></textarea>
         <br/>
         <button id="send_email">Send Email</button>
         <span id="message"></span>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var app = express();
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    auth: {
        user: "******",
        pass: "***"
    }
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});

app.get('/send', function(req, res) {
    //code to send e-mail.
    //Will be shown soon.
    var mailOptions = {
        to: req.query.to,
        subject: req.query.subject,
        text: req.query.text
    }
    console.log(mailOptions);
    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.end("error");
        } else {
            console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
            res.end("sent");
        }
    });

});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Express Started on Port 3000");
});
```

at `user`, `pass` in `server.js` file use the valid mail id and its password.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I am actually using the exact same example you made use of. :) My issue is the integration with other API calls and AngularJs and Digitalocean.